# Building unprivileged (userns) LXC container from scratch, by migrating a privileged container to be unprivileged

Tags: linux, lxc, userns

How can I build a privileged LXC (1.0.3) container (that part I know) and then migrate it successfully to be run unprivileged? That is, I'd like to `debootstrap` it myself or adjust the `lxc-ubuntu` template (commonly under `/usr/share/lxc/templates`) in order for this to work.

Here's why I am asking this question. If you look at the `lxc-ubuntu` template, you'll notice:

```bash
# Detect use under userns (unsupported)
for arg in "$@"; do
    [ "$arg" = "--" ] && break
    if [ "$arg" = "--mapped-uid" -o "$arg" = "--mapped-gid" ]; then
        echo "This template can't be used for unprivileged containers." 1>&2
        echo "You may want to try the \"download\" template instead." 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Following the use of `LXC_MAPPED_GID` and `LXC_MAPPED_UID` in the referenced `lxc-download` template, though, there seems to be nothing particularly special. In fact all it does is to adjust the file ownership (`chgrp` + `chown`). But it's possible that the extended attributes in the `download` template are fine-tuned already to accomplish whatever "magic" is needed.

In the comments to [this blog post by Stéphane Graber](https://www.stgraber.org/2014/01/17/lxc-1-0-unprivileged-containers/) Stéphane tells a commenter that

> There’s no easy way to do that unfortunately, you’d need to update
>   your container config to match that from an unprivileged container,
>   move the container’s directory over to the unprivileged user you want
>   it to run as, then use Serge’s uidshift program to change the
>   ownership of all files.

... and to:

- have a look at https://jenkins.linuxcontainers.org/ for the packages built for the `download` template
- check out `uidmapshift` from [here](https://launchpad.net/~serge-hallyn/+archive/nsexec)

  - This program appears to roughly do `lxc-usernsexec -m b:0:1000:1 -m b:1:190000:1 -- /bin/chown 1:1 $file` as explained in [`lxc-usernsexec(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lxc-usernsexec.1.html)

But there are no further pointers.

**So my question is: how can I take an ordinary (privileged) LXC container that I have built myself (having `root` and all) and migrate it to become an unprivileged container?** Even if you can't provide a script or so, it would be great to know which points to consider and how they affect the ability to run the unprivileged LXC container. I can come up with a script on my own and pledge to post it as an answer to this question if a solution can be found :)

*Note:* Although I am using Ubuntu 14.04, this is a *generic* question.

Answer (score 6):

I was just doing something very similar, moving KVM VMs into unprivileged LXC.

I was using system containers for this (so they can be started automatically on boot), but with mapped UID/GIDs (user namespaces).

1. edit /etc/subuid,subgid (I mapped uid/gids 10M-100M to root and use 100K per container)
2. for first container, use u/gids 10000000-10099999 in /var/lib/lxc/CTNAME/config
3. mount the container storage on /var/lib/lxc/CTNAME/rootfs (or do nothing if you don't use separate volume/dataset/whatever per container)
4. chown 10000000:10000000 /var/lib/lxc/CTNAME/rootfs
5. setfacl -m u:10000000:x /var/lib/lxc (or simply chmod o+x /var/lib/lxc)
6. lxc-usernsexec -m b:0:10000000:100000 -- /bin/bash

Now you're in the first container user namespace. Everything is the same, but your process thinks it's uid is 0, when in fact in the host namespace it's uid 10000000. Check /proc/self/uid_map to see whether your uid is mapped or not. You will notice you can no longer read from /root and it seems to be owned by nobody/nogroup.

While in the user namespace, I rsync from the original host.

Outside the user namespace, you will see that the files in /var/lib/lxc/CTNAME/rootfs are now owned not by the expected (same) uids as the origin installation, but rather 10000000+remote_uid. This is what you want.

That's it. When you have your data sync'ed, remove everything from container's /etc/fstab so it won't try to mount things, and it should start. There might be other things to change, check what the LXC template for the containerised distro does. You can definitely remove the kernel, grub, ntp and any hardware-probing packages in the container (you don't even have to run it, you can chroot to the container from the user namespace)

If you don't have a running remote VM, you can also mount the original VM storage in the host namespace and rsync/SSH back in to localhost. The effect will be the same.

If you (as it seems) simply want to change your privileged container to unprivileged, you might as well just add the uid/gid mapping, add a mapping as above to your container config and then do something along the lines of:

```
for i in `seq 0 65535`; do
  find /var/lib/lxc/CTNAME/rootfs -uid $i -exec chown $((10000000+i)) \{\} \;
  find /var/lib/lxc/CTNAME/rootfs -gid $i -exec chgrp $((10000000+i)) \{\} \;
done
```

That should be all that needs doing, now you should be able to run the container unprivileged. This example above is extremely inefficient, uidshift will probably do a better job at this (but I haven't used it yet).

HTH.

Comment: the rsync part isn't very clear: after `lxc-usernsexec` everything appears to be owned by 65534 and nothing can be copied. Is it possible to go with `lxc-clone`? I've tried `lxc-clone` but got "Device or resource busy - error unlinking /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc /dev/console" on `lxc-start`.

Comment: I just wrote a tool to efficiently convert UID/GIDs of the containers' files, basically for replacing the conversion by something more general. Sharing it in a good hope someone will find it handy -- https://github.com/exaexa/chownmap

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to warn that Borut Mrak's example code will change ownership of files on the host system as well when symbolic links point to those files in the container! Not what you would want at all!

You should use -h flag for chown/chgrp and/or -mount for find in case you have dedicated filesystem.

Here's my faster smarter version:

```
find "/var/lib/lxc/$name/rootfs" -mount -uid '-65536' -printf '%U\n'|sort -n|uniq|while read i; do
        find "/var/lib/lxc/$name/rootfs" -mount -uid "$i" -exec chown -h "$((200000+i))" \{\} \;
done

find "/var/lib/lxc/$name/rootfs" -mount -gid '-65536' -printf '%G\n'|sort -n|uniq|while read i; do
        find "/var/lib/lxc/$name/rootfs" -mount -gid "$i" -exec chgrp -h "$((200000+i))" \{\} \;
done
```

Comment: Have some reputation. Thanks for the late answer. This looks indeed like the smarter solution, compared to the existing one. Alas, it's the same as `uidmapshift`. Problem is that it's not sufficient to only fix up the ownership, but it's a first important step.

Answer (score 1):

[Alpine Linux](http://alpinelinux.org) now uses [`uidmapshift` converted into `lua`](https://github.com/jirutka/uidmapshift) to [convert privileged containers to unprivileged](https://it-offshore.co.uk/linux/alpine-linux/82-alpine-linux-unprivileged-lxc-containers). Take a look at the [`initd` script](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/blob/bea7246a8fbf0e2ab41909597edd00fdb36a7793/community/lxcfs/lxcfs.initd) to see the other folder permissions & requirements that are set / created. (`/etc/subuid` & `/etc/subgid`)

Answer (score 1):

## for clowning container

```
SUBUID_OFFSET=-65536
SUBGID_OFFSET=-65536
cd rootfs || exit 1
find .|while read i; do SUBUID=$(stat --format=%u $i); SUBGID=$(stat --format=%g $i); NEW_SUBUID=$((SUBUID+SUBUID_OFFSET)); NEW_SUBGID=$((SUBGID+SUBGID_OFFSET)); echo "chown -h $NEW_SUBUID.$NEW_SUBGID $i"; done
```

## for migrating linux system

```
SUBUID=100000
SUBGID=100000
cd rootfs || exit 1
find .|while read i; do CURRENT_UID=$(stat --format=%u $i); CURRENT_GID=$(stat --format=%g $i); NEW_SUBUID=$((CURRENT_UID+SUBUID)); NEW_SUBGID=$((CURRENT_GID+SUBGID)); echo "chown -h $NEW_SUBUID.$NEW_SUBGID $i"; done
```

Comment: For trees with weird names, here is a null-terminated version (bash required for the `read -d''`) :
`find . -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do CURRENT_UID=$(stat --format=%u "$i"); CURRENT_GID=$(stat --format=%g "$i"); NEW_SUBUID=$((CURRENT_UID+SUBUID)); NEW_SUBGID=$((CURRENT_GID+SUBGID)); chown -h $NEW_SUBUID.$NEW_SUBGID "$i"; done`

Comment: Hello, it's me again :)
I went into trouble with a container having some hardlinks, thus doubling the uid-shift. Here is my new script :
`export SUBUID=100000`
`export SUBGID=100000`
`find debian-bullseye-lxccreate/rootfs -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do CURRENT_UID=$(stat --format=%u "$i"); CURRENT_GID=$(stat --format=%g "$i"); NEW_SUBUID=$((CURRENT_UID+SUBUID)); NEW_SUBGID=$((CURRENT_GID+SUBGID)); [ $CURRENT_UID -lt $SUBUID] && [ $CURRENT_GID -lt $SUBGID ] && chown -h $NEW_SUBUID.$NEW_SUBGID "$i" || echo "uid or gid already changed for $i ?"; done`